# Double-use of C# iterator works unexpectedly

Tags: c#, linq, iterator

This is my first go at coding in C# - I have a background in C/Python/Javascript/Haskell.

Why does the program below work?  I would expect this to work in Haskell, as lists are immutable, but I am struggling with how I can use the same iterator `nums` twice, without error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nums = new List<int?>() { 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };
            var lastNums = new List<int?>() { null } .Concat(nums);
            var changesAndNulls = lastNums.Zip(nums,
                (last, curr) => (last == null || last != curr) ? curr : null
            );
            var changes = from changeOrNull in changesAndNulls where changeOrNull != null select changeOrNull;

            foreach (var change in changes) {
              Console.WriteLine("change: " + change);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of the code works in unexpected way?

Comment: Where is the double use?

Comment: nums is not `IEnumerator<T>`, it's `IEnumerable<T>'` which has `GetEnumerator()` method to invoke arbitrary times

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth `nums` and `lastNums` are both accessing `nums` as an iterator, and are being used in parallel in the `Zip`.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks, that's it - if turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @chrisdew `nums` isn't an "iterator", it is an "iteratable" collection, and is simply being iterated over twice, which is allowed because each iterator walking over it is its own independent state machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `nums` is not `IEnumerator<T>` (iterator), it's `IEnumarable<T>` and `IEnumarable <T>` has `GetEnumerator()` method which can be invoked as *many times* as required:

```
IEnumerable<int?> nums = new List<int?>() { 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };

// Linq gets enumerator to do Concat 
using (var iterator1 = nums.GetEnumerator()) {
   while (iterator1.MoveNext()) {
     ...
   }
}

...

// Linq gets (fresh!) enumerator to do Zip 
using (var iterator2 = nums.GetEnumerator()) {
   while (iterator2.MoveNext()) {
    ...
   }
}
```

So `IEnumerable<T>` is a *factory* producing `IEnumerator<T>` instances (and it is a `IEnumerator<T>` that can't be *re-used*)

Comment: It's not really relevant to the question and nobody ever uses this feature, but `IEnumerator<T>` *can* be reused by calling `Reset()`. (Although it wouldn't work here, since the two uses of the enumerator are parallel.)

Answer (score 2):

A `List<int?>` implements the interface `IEnumerable<int?>`. That means it has a method called `GetEnumerator()`.
This method returns a new `Enumerator<int?>` object used to iterate over all the items.

You are calling `GetEnumerator()` (in the background) when you use it inside a foreach loop or when you call one of the many extension methods like `Concat()` (which call `GetEnumerator()` themselves).

I suggest you take a tutorial on C#. It is a very different language than Haskell and it has some very unique features.
Just for starters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_syntax